# Axios Authorization not working - VueJS + Django

Tags: django, vue.js, graphql, axios, graphene-django

I am trying to build an application using VueJS and Django. I am also using Graphene-Django library, as the project utilize GraphQL.

Now, The authentication works fine and i get a JWT Token back. 
But when i use the token for other queries that need authentication, i got this error in Vue:

```
"Error decoding signature"
```

and the Django Log also returns this:

```
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: Error decoding signature

jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Not enough segments

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

the bizarre thing is that the same query when executed in Postman just works fine.

As i mentioned in the title is use Axios for my requests, here's an example of a request:

```
axios({
  method: "POST",
  headers: { Authorization: "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("token") },
  data: {
    query: `{
        dailyAppoint (today: "${today}") {
            id
            dateTime
        }
     }`
    }
});
```

Note: It uses 'JWT' not 'Bearer' because somehow 'Bearer' didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a request interceptor to set the Authorization header:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
   if (localStorage.getItem("token") != null)
     config.headers["Authorization"] = "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("token");
   return config;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, couple of questions, does you API work without Vue.js from curl. Generate token, check API from curl.

If it does, then check the Headers sent from the request, from Network Inspector, mozilla dev tools/chrome devtools. And update your Post with those RAW Headers.

This particular error arises when your public key is unable to decode the string[token] signed by your private key. Which ultimately means the access token has been tampered with. It could also mean you're sending values like 'unkown'-- JS state initialization error.

Check the RAW headers of the request. It'll help.

Comment: I checked with Chrome devtools as you adviced and indeed it was sending: `Authorization: JWT undefined` do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Once you obtain the token do you set it away in the local storage, if so share that code.

Comment: i added an Axios interceptor for my requests. apparently that's the best practice, and now it works.